# Python native parsing of path names with unknown path separators

Tags: python, filepath

I am working on a parser for a configuration file and was wondering if there was a python native way to deal with path names that are strings which could have been created for any operating system.

Example:

```
pathName1 = r".../This/is/a/relative/path"
pathName2 = r"...\This\is\a\relative\path"
```

would be interpreted as equal, and be usable to access a file on the operating system that is executing the code.

Right now I have a regular expression hack which replaces the offending separators with os.path.sep, but I figured this must be a common enough problem that there might be a python-native way of doing this.

Comment: `...\This\is\a\relative\path` is a valid Linux filename.

Comment: You might not be aware that `/` usually acts as a path separator in Windows, in addition to the more cannonical backslash. You might be able to sidestep this question if you use `/` as a path separator in all files that are supposed to work across platforms.

Comment: @MagnusHoff: I guess it would not be the end of the world to do what you suggest and just require the use of `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Andrew Sledge  is right in terms of generating paths using `os.path.join`, but if you are stuck with a string that could be either style and you want to normalize it, here is one way to do it:

```
import re
import os
def normalize_path(path):
    return os.path.normpath(os.sep.join(re.split(r'\\|/', path)))
```

Usage:

```
>>> normalize_path("/usr/local/share/myfile")
'/usr/local/share/myfile'
>>> normalize_path("C:\My Documents\Users/music.mp3")
'C:/My Documents/Users/music.mp3'
>>> normalize_path("~/Documents///report.pdf")
'~/Documents/report.pdf'
>>> normalize_path("/tmp/subdir/subsubdir/.././//")
'/tmp/subdir'
>>> normalize_path("../Photos/.")
'../Photos'
```

the for usage, you would just use normal [os.path](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) stuff:

```
>>> os.path.abspath(normalize_path("../Photos/."))
'/private/tmp/Photos'
>>> os.path.expanduser(normalize_path("~/Documents///report.pdf"))
'/Users/matt/Documents/report.pdf'
>>> os.path.join(normalize_path("/tmp//./subdir"), "myfile.txt")
'/tmp/subdir/myfile.txt'
>>> os.path.dirname(normalize_path("~/Documents///report.pdf"))
'~/Documents'
>>> os.path.basename(normalize_path("~/Documents///report.pdf"))
'report.pdf'
```

Comment: This is more concise than my hack, and it sounds like there is not a more "native" way of doing this.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much right. I did add a couple usage examples for easy reference.

Answer (score 1):

Python is able to deal with both types transparently using `os` methods (`os.chdir()`, `os.path.*`), even if some funny things may happen between platforms; but I assume that configuration files can be platform or even computer-dependent.

By the way, take care to `\`: in Python code, either you need to escape them (`"\\some\\path"`) or to use raw strings (`r"\some path"), even if in text files it can be written normally.

---

**Edit**

If using relative paths, your best choice is definitly to use something "dynamic", based on `os.path.join`. Example:

```
test_files_path = os.path.join('..', '..', 'tests', 'resources')  
# ^ would result in something platform-dependent
my_test_file_one = os.path.join(test_files_path, 'test1.txt')
```

More subtle: imported modules have a `__file__` attribute, so you can use it for testing. Example:

```
import my_module
test_files_path = os.path.join( os.path.dirname(my_module.__file__), 'tests')
my_test_file_one = os.path.join(test_files_path, 'test1.txt')
```

Comment: In general I agree that configuration files can be platform or computer dependent, in this case this is not really possible. The configuration files are supplying data driven tests with their test data, and the test suite needs to run platform independently. The extra work to make the reading in of configuration files platform independent seems far more convenient than creating multiple configuration files for each test. Thank for mentioning the backslash, I oversimplified my example. I am using raw strings, I'll change that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of ways of doing this. The most common way is with `os.path.join`.

```
path = os.path.join("This", "is", "a", "relative", "path")
```

will return This/is/a/path for POSIX and This\is\a\path for Windows.

Comment: OP's question is about finding a function such that `f(pathName1) == f(pathName2)` on any platform.

Comment: I must agree with Blender, your answer, in a sense, is the opposite of what I am asking.